# PyMongo - How to compare the given array exactly matches with the document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a MongoDB document with the following attributes:

```
{
  "label": [
    "ibc",
    "ibd",
    "ibe"
  ],
  "location": "vochelle st"
}
```

and I have to return the document only if the documents label exactly matches the given array i.e., `["ibc","ibd"]` and for the same, I am using the query:

```
db.collection.find({"location":"vochelle st","dock_label":{"$all":["ibc", "ibd"]}})
```

Actual Response:

```
{
  "label": [
    "ibc",
    "ibd",
    "ibe"
  ],
  "location": "vochelle st"
}
```

Expected Response:

```
{}
```

Since the label "ibe" doesn't exist in the given array, the expected result has to be the empty dictionary.

Comment: Is it `idc` or `ibc` in `{"$all":["idc", "ibd"]}`? If `idc`, the result will be no document.

Comment: It is ibc, excuse the typo error @YongShun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `$size` in your query

```
db.collection.find({
  location: "vochelle st",
  label: {
    $all: [
      "ibc",
      "ibd"
    ],
    $size: 2
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7PDzojglVGl)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [`$setIntersection`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) to intersect both `label` and input array.
2. Compare both intersected array *(from 1)* and `label` arrays are matched via `$eq`.

```
db.collection.find({
  "location": "vochelle st",
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $setIntersection: [
          "$label",
          [
            "ibc",
            "ibd"
          ]
        ]
      },
      "$label"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hY11cAZ9xzZ)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the array exactly matches your input, you don't need any operator, just compare it with your value:

```
db.collection.find({"location":"vochelle st","label": ["ibc", "ibd"]})
```